# i want to display apple in green colour instead of mango in red colour when mouse over the mango

Tags: css, html, hover

**strong text**this is my html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hov.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one">
            <p>mango</p>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <p>apple</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my style sheet

```
#two
{
    display:none;
}
#one
{
   background-color :red;
}
```

i want to display apple in green colour(bg colour) **instead of** mango in red colour(bg colour) when **mouse over** the mango ,i'm tried the following codes ,but that's not help me..

```
#one :hover + #two
{
    display:block;
}
#one :hover ~ #two
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

Comment: Do you wish to hide mango and show apple ?

Comment: yeah ,i wish to do so and the background colour too.

Comment: I couldn't think of CSS only solution. This might need JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CSS only solution. The trick is to overlay the second element on top of the first and then hide it. On hover, show the second div.
NOTE: I didn't use `visibility` because one can't hover over invisible elements.

Here's the snippet:

```css
#one {
  display:block;
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: -34px;
}

#two:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hov.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one">
            <p>mango</p>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <p>apple</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I must point out that this may not be the ideal solution if in case you're attaching handlers like 'onclick' on the bottom div (mango), because the second div is 'hiding' the bottom one.

Comment: yeah.,i know that,but some time we need to go through the fake methods like this to get the output we want with some particular  parameters.thank you for your code.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the css of `apple` on hover of `mango` like below

```js
$('#mango').hover(function(){
  $('#apple').css('background-color','greenyellow').show();
  $(this).hide();
});
$('#apple').mouseout(function(){
  $('#mango').show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
#two
{
    display:none;
}
#one,#mango
{
   background-color :red;
}
#one:hover+#two{
    display:block;    
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
#apple{
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
  <p>mango</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <p>apple</p>
</div>
<br>
<h3>With jQuery</h3>
 <p id="mango">mango</p>
 <p id="apple">apple</p>
```

jQuery version will hide `mango` & show `apple` on hover of `mango` and will do the reverse when mouse pointer is away from the apple.

Comment: but this is not i'm really asked...i need to hide the mango with red color when visible the apple with green color

Comment: What?? you want to show apple on hover of `mango` and then hide the mango, Then I don't think that's possible with css. You need javascript/jQuery to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

here is what you want:

```js
function green() {
  document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "apple";
}

function red() {
  document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "mango";
}
```

```css
#one {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" onmouseover="green()" onmouseout="red()">
  <p id="text">mango</p>
</div>
```

Live [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/29Lph26r/)

Comment: yeah...this is what i'm required

Answer (score 0):

```
#one {
  display:block;
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  display:none;
  background-color: green;
}

#one:hover+#two {
    display: block;
  }
```

**Codepen**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEzQKm

Comment: i appreciate your effort.but this not what i'm wanted.this is just same as the above code.

Comment: I was creating the codepen and didn't see the other post, ok

Comment: check the side bar on link given below..http://preview.themeforest.net/item/flatkit-app-ui-kit/full_screen_preview/13231484?_ga=1.266136847.1446846814.1470679913

Comment: i want to create one like that

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a CSS only solution for your problem. Here is an JavaScript way of doing.

```js
function toggle(_this, txt) {
  //Change the text
  _this.innerHTML = txt;

  //Change the color
  _this.classList.toggle("green");
  _this.classList.toggle("red");
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hov.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="one" class="red" onmouseover="toggle(this,'apple')" onmouseout="toggle(this,'mango' )">
    mango
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but this not work on mouse over...this is work based on mouse click

Comment: Yes. If you hide `mango` in red background, obviously it's hover won't work and `apple` in green color will disappear!